# undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass(RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm writing a feature spec for setting a comment in the database. Everything seems straight forward but I'm getting a nil class error on comments and I can't figure out why? I'll post some code and see if anybody can help me debug this problem.

SPEC:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Create a Comment" do
 scenario "Customer can leave additional information" do
 visit "/comments/new"

 user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
 fill_in "Email", with: user.email
 fill_in "Password", with: user.password
 click_button "Sign in"

 fill_in "comment_fav_drink", with: "Latte"
 click_button "Send"

 expect(page).to have_current_path('subscribers/search')
 expect(page).to have_content("Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created")

 end
end
```

CONTROLLERS:

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @comment = Comment.new
 end

  def create
   @subscriber = Subscriber.order('updated_at desc').first
   @comment = @subscriber.comments.build(comments_params)
 if @comment.save
   flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
   redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
  else
   render "new"
  end
end

private

def comments_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink, :subscriber_id)
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where you're calling the `comments` method is `@subscriber.comments` in your `create` action, which means that `@subscriber` is `nil`, looking back up you set that to `Subscriber.order('updated_at desc').first` which means that returned `nil` which means you have no subscribers in your database when your test is being run, which matches what I can see of your test (ie. you're not creating any subscribers)